# How to pass variadic arguments in ModelContainer(for:) in other init?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I want to initialize my class with initializer:

```swift
init(for forTypes: any PersistentModel.Type...) {
    container = try? ModelContainer(for: forTypes)
}
```

But I got an error:

```
Cannot pass array of type 'any PersistentModel.Type...' as variadic arguments of type 'any PersistentModel.Type'
```

How can I solve this? I've tried passing without `any`, that gets me to another error:

```
Use of protocol 'PersistentModel' as a type must be written 'any PersistentModel'
```

Comment: Try to remove ‘Type’ from Persistant mode.type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you can't pass on a variadic parameter, once inside the function (init) it's an array and there's no init for `ModelContainer` that takes an array of `PersistentModel`.

One workaround is to use an init that takes a `Schema`

```
init(for types: any PersistentModel.Type...) throws {
    container = try ModelContainer(for: Schema(types))
}
```